# While loop causing function to return 0 in c

Tags: c, random

I have the following c function working on implementing a rejection sampler. MersenneTwiser.h generates a random number between 0 and 1. The issue I'm having is with the rnorm function. I'm using a while loop to reject some samples. It's nonsense at the moment as it's not finished. In it's current form, the program returns 0.00000.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include"MersenneTwister.h"
MTRand rng;

double p;
double prop;
int sign;


double dubexp(double theta){
    p = rng.rand();

    if ((p-0.5) > 0) sign= 1;
    if ((p-0.5) < 0) sign= -1;

    prop = -(1/theta)*sign*log(1-2*abs(p-0.5));
    return(prop);
}


double u;
double theta;
double t;
double z;
double c;
double x;

double rnorm(double theta, double c){

    t=rng.rand();
    while (z == t)
    {
        x=dubexp(theta);
        u=rng.rand();
        z=x;

    }
    return z;
}

int main(){
    theta=1;
    c=1;
    
    u = rnorm(theta,c);
    printf("%f",u);
}
```

However if I remove the while loop, it returns the correct value of z. As below:

```
double rnorm(double theta, double c){

    t=rng.rand();
     x=dubexp(theta);
        u=rng.rand();
        z=x;
    
    
    return z;
}
```

Comment: There is already an answer explaining the exact problem you face, so I'll use the comment here to ask you re-think your usage of global variables and if there may be a better way to organize things.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I assume you are hinting towards creating a data-structure (struct) instead and passing a pointer/reference to that around? If so, I agree with you :)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 5):

The while-loop never runs

```
double rnorm(double theta, double c){

    t=rng.rand();
    while (z == t) // <-- this condition is never true, so the loop doesn't run and the function just returns z
    {
        x=dubexp(theta);
        u=rng.rand();
        z=x;

    }
    return z;
}
```

See the comment above.

Also, `z` is defined globally. Global vars and static vars are initialized to zero. That's the reason.

Comment: Wow, stupid error. Should have sat on this for an hour longer. Thank you for the debugging help!

Comment: No problem dude. A fresh pair of eyes is sometimes all it takes :)

Comment: @TannerPhillips Honest question: Do you know how to step through your code using a debugger? If not, this could be a great reason to learn that.

Comment: No. I'm a long time R programmer and am just learning C (obvously). I've got Visual Studio Code up and running, but I am struggling to debug compiled code. I basically just build a small part, modify my main function to run my code so far, then move on. I haven't really learning anything about debugging.

Comment: You can run the C code "one line at a time" with a debugger, and watch the variables and see them change for each statement etc. That is a powerful tool when debugging and I'd advise that you learn how to use one. Visual Studio's debugger is really good in my opinion, but unfortunately I have no experience with Visual Studio Code (the cross-platform editor).

Comment: @TannerPhillips I found a few video tutorials on youtube on how to debug a program in Visual Studio Code. It requires some setup and is a bit more involved than in "normal" Visual Studio, but after the setup, it seems to work much the same way: you can step through each line and see the values of variables for each statement.

Comment: That sounds lovely. Thanks a ton!